# Dropdown UI component

Tags: javascript

I've implement a custom dropdown, that help to find users from data. Each item have a userpic, first name and last name. And my task is create a dropdown with settings like use picture or not. I coded it in `create` function, in a loop with `if`-statement: `if (is_use_picture) { /* ... */ }`. It would be great if I could get some feedback on this code.

```
function Dropdown(dropdown, data, is_use_picture, is_multiselect) {

    /**
     * Reformat a data and create a dropdown.
     */

    var formatted_data;

    this.init = function() {
        formatted_data = reformat(data);

        var DROPDOWN_ITEMS_LENGTH = 10;
        var result = new Array(DROPDOWN_ITEMS_LENGTH);

        for (var i = 0; i < DROPDOWN_ITEMS_LENGTH; ++i) {
            result[i] = data[i];
        }

        create(result, is_use_picture, is_multiselect);
    };


    /**
     * @param {Array.<Object>} data.
     * @return {Array.<Object>} result.
     */

    var reformat = function(data) {
        var len = response.items.length;
        var result = new Array(len);

        var first_name;
        var last_name;
        var domain;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            first_name = response.items[i].first_name.toLowerCase();
            last_name = response.items[i].last_name.toLowerCase();
            domain = response.items[i].domain.toLowerCase();

            result[i] = {
                'item_info': response.items[i],
                'first_name': first_name,
                'last_name': last_name,
                'domain': domain
            };
        }

        return result;
    };


    /**
     * Create and insert dropdown items.
     * @param {Array.<Object>} data.
     * @param {bool} is_use_picture.
     */

    var dropdown_items;
    var dropdown_items_length;

    var create = function(data, is_use_picture) {
        var item_node = document.createElement('div');
        item_node.className = 'dropdown-item cf';

        var text_node = document.createElement('span');

        if (is_use_picture) {
            var picture_node = document.createElement('span');
            picture_node.className = 'dropdown-item-picture';
        }

        var len = data.length;
        var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

        var i = 0;

        while (i < len) {
            var item = item_node.cloneNode(true);
            item.setAttribute('data-index', i);
            item.setAttribute('data-id', data[i].id);
            item.addEventListener('click', select);

            if (is_use_picture) {
                var picture = picture_node.cloneNode(true);
                picture.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + data[i].photo_50 + ')';
                item.appendChild(picture);
            }

            var text = text_node.cloneNode(true);
            text.className = 'dropdown-item-text';
            text.textContent = data[i].first_name + ' ' + data[i].last_name;
            item.appendChild(text);

            docfrag.appendChild(item);

            i++;
        }

        dropdown_items_length = i;

        clean();

        dropdown_content.appendChild(docfrag);

        dropdown_items = dropdown.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item');
    };


    /**
     * Open/close a dropdown.
     */

    var dropdown_content = dropdown.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
    var is_open;

    var open = function() {
        dropdown_content.classList.remove('hidden');
        is_open = true;
    };

    var close = function() {
        dropdown_content.className += ' hidden';
        is_open = false;
    };

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        if (is_open && event.keyCode === 27) {
            close();
        }
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        if (is_open && event.keyCode == 0) {
            var element = event.target;

            while (element !== document) {
                if (element.className === 'dropdown') {
                    return;
                }
                element = element.parentNode;
            }

            close();
        }
    }, false);


    /**
     *
     */

    var clean = function() {
        while (dropdown_content.hasChildNodes()) {
            dropdown_content.removeChild(dropdown_content.firstChild);
        }
    };


    /**
     * Navigation by dropdown.
     */

    var UP_KEY_CODE = 38;
    var DOWN_KEY_CODE = 40;
    var SCROLL_STEP = 66;

    var keydown_count = -1;

    var hover = function(event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        if (event.keyCode === UP_KEY_CODE || event.keyCode === DOWN_KEY_CODE) {
            if (event.keyCode === UP_KEY_CODE) {
                keydown_count--;

                if (keydown_count < 0) {
                    keydown_count = dropdown_items_length - 1;
                    dropdown_content.scrollTop = SCROLL_STEP * dropdown_items_length;
                }

                if (keydown_count < (dropdown_items_length - 3)) {
                    dropdown_content.scrollTop -= SCROLL_STEP;
                }

            } else if (event.keyCode === DOWN_KEY_CODE) {
                keydown_count++;

                if (keydown_count >= dropdown_items_length) {
                    keydown_count = 0;
                    dropdown_content.scrollTop = 0;
                }

                if (keydown_count > 2) {
                    dropdown_content.scrollTop += SCROLL_STEP;
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < dropdown_items_length; ++i) {
                dropdown_items[i].classList.remove('dropdown-item--hover');
            }

            dropdown_items[keydown_count].className += ' dropdown-item--hover';
        }

    };


    /**
     *
     */

    var select = function() {
        if (!is_multiselect) {
            close();
        }

        dropdown_input.value = '';

        return this.getAttribute('data-id');
    };


    /**
     *
     */

    var dropdown_input = dropdown.querySelector('.dropdown-input');

    dropdown_input.addEventListener('keydown', hover, false);

    var dropdown_input_wrap = dropdown.querySelector('.dropdown-input-wrap');

    dropdown_input_wrap.addEventListener('click', open, false);

}
```

I use this code to init dropdown:

```
var dropdown = new Dropdown(document.getElementById('dropdown'), response.items, true, false);

dropdown.init();
```

Comment: how would you use this function? you only seem to allow init to be called?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I use `init()` function. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what you're asking here, but if you're trying to go for an Object-Oriented approach here, you should be doing it like this:

```
function MyObject( ... ) {
    ...
}

MyObject.prototype.my_func = function( ... ) {
    ...
}
```

For example, your `init` function would become the following (assumes you've done this for your other functions/variables as well):

```
Dropdown.prototype.init = function() {
    this.formatted_data = this.reformat(this.data);

    var DROPDOWN_ITEMS_LENGTH = 10;
    var result = new Array(DROPDOWN_ITEMS_LENGTH);

    for (var i = 0; i < DROPDOWN_ITEMS_LENGTH; ++i) {
        result[i] = this.data[i];
    }

    this.create(result, this.is_use_picture, this.is_multiselect);
};
```

Also, empty comments, like the below example, should be either removed, or should have some details added to them.

```
/**
 *
 */
```

Comment: You should add more details to your answer. Can you give an actual example of how you'd rewrite part of the code using OO principles?

Comment: @Phrancis I've added a few more details now.

Comment: Upvoted accordingly